# Doing a foreach and ordering using $i++; for example but depending on a parent id in PHP

Tags: php

**question updated:**

I've the next array, obtained from a nested sortable tree. The `$key` means the id of a PAGE and the `$value` it's the parent id. In my MySQL table I've to modify the `parent_id` of every page (when updating) and store the ORDER of a PAGE depending of the parent ID.

In the next example I've 3 ids with `parent_id` = 1: 5, 2 and 3. I've to update on MySQL 5,2 and 3 saving like:

```
UPDATE pages SET parent_id=1,order=0 WHERE id=5
UPDATE pages SET parent_id=1,order=1 WHERE id=2
UPDATE pages SET parent_id=1,order=2 WHERE id=3

Array
(
    [1] => 0
    [5] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 3
    [6] => 3
)
```

How I can handle this with PHP? I'll do a `foreach` for every page id and send a MySQL update on each of loop for the `foreach`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to be clearer.  What do you mean by an "order number ... depending on the parent"?

Comment: Your explanation isn't clear. What do you want at the end? YOu want to change all the keys so they're in proper ascending order?

Comment: That array represents a tree, right? You should work on your coherence and rewrite the question.

Comment: I've updated the question with more information. Sorry but my main language is not English and I do as best I can. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll just want to use another variable to keep track of the last parent id used and then compare to see if it changed.

```
// make sure the array is sorted by parent id
asort($array);

$last_parent = -1;
foreach ($array as $id => $parent_id)
{
    if ($last_parent != $parent_id)
        $order = 0;

    $query = 'UPDATE pages SET parent_id = ' . $parent_id . ', order = ' . $order . ' WHERE id = ' . $id;

    $last_parent = $parent_id;
    $order++;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i think that this will fail. `sort($array)` will sort like: [1]=>0, [2]=>1, [3]=>1... but If I have this will fail: `[1]=>0, [2]=>3, [3]=>1, [4]=>3, [5]=>4`

Comment: Oops, you're right. It's asort() you want, not sort(). I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you want to order the array based on the value?

In which case you would use

```
sort($array);
```